# String with allowed chars

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a clean way to get a string containing only allowed characters?

for example:

```
NSString* myStr = @"a5&/Öñ33";
NSString* allowedChars = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
NSString* result = [myStr stringWIthAllowedChrs:allowedChars];
```

result should now be `@"a533"`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the cleanest, but you could separate the string using a character set, and then combine the resulting array using an empty string.

```
// Create a character set with every character not in allowedChars
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:allowedChars] invertedSet];
// Split the original string at any occurrence of those characters
NSArray *splitString = [myStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];
// Combine the result into a string
NSString *result = [splitString componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple and easy to customize and understand approach:

```
NSString* myStr = @"a5&/Öñ33";
NSString* allowedChars = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
NSCharacterSet *set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:allowedChars] invertedSet];
NSString *result = myStr;
NSRange range = [result rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set];
while (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    result = [result stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    range = [result rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest-

```
NSString* result = @"";

for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [myStr length]; i++)
{
    unichar charArr[1] = {[myStr characterAtIndex:i]};
    NSString* charString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:charArr length:1];

    if([allowedChars rangeOfString:charString].location != NSNotFound)
        result = [result stringByAppendingString:charString];
}

return result;
```

Comment: It would be much better to use an `NSMutableString` for `result`.